# proxy pass for activeMQ

Tags: apache-2.2, activemq

I have a apache server that I'm trying to use for proxy access my activeMQ admin page. I am able to load the inital landing page properly, but I can't seem to load any of the sub-pages (Queues, Connections, etc.). My proxypass rules on the apache server are the following:

```
ProxyPass /foo http://10.5.124.108:8161/admin
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://10.5.124.108:8161/admin
```

The activeMQ installation included a activemq-httpd.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/. Proxy connections there are enabled:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
Allow from all
Order allow,deny
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /admin http://localhost:8161/admin
ProxyPassReverse /admin http://localhost:8161/admin
ProxyPass /message http://localhost:8161/admin/send
ProxyPassReverse /message http://localhost:8161/admin/send
```

From what I've read the proxypass rules should be recursive (the rule for /foo should also work for /foo/bar). Is there something else that I'm missing here that's preventing me from accessing pages beyond the initial admin landing page?

Answer (score 2):

mod_proxy doesn't re-write links in the destination page, so while you can view the initial page, a common problem is that links to sub-pages contain a hostname or URL that doesn't point back to the proxy frontend that you have access to. This should be easy to spot in the html source or by just hovering on the links.

If that's going on, it might be possible to configure AMQ to use the hostname of the proxy host rather than its own.

Proxypass URL's are recursive but again, only when the link is correct. If you remap /message to /admin/send and there's a link under there going to /admin/send/foo - it's not going to get redirected to /message/foo. You could probably add some mod_rewrite foo to get that to happen, but I do not believe it's part of mod_proxy.

Comment: so...it the url works when I remove the globbed session ID bit on the end, and format it thusly:http://foo.corp.bar.com/admin/queues.jsp guess I should've tried that in the first place! I'll make direct links to these so no one has to dig into the admin page and use the "bunk" url.